# Neo4j regex string matching not returning expected results

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to use the Neo4j 2.1.5 regex matching in Cypher and running into problems.

I need to implement a full text search on specific fields that a user has access to. The access requirement is key and is what prevents me from just dumping everything into a Lucene instance and querying that way.  The access system is dynamic and so I need to query for the set of nodes that a particular user has access to and then within those nodes perform the search.  I would really like to match the set of nodes against a Lucene query, but I can't figure out how to do that so I'm just using basic regex matching for now.  My problem is that Neo4j doesn't always return the expected results.

For example, I have about 200 nodes with one of them being the following:

```
( i:node {name: "Linear Glass Mosaic Tiles", description: "Introducing our new Rip Curl linear glass mosaic tiles. This Caribbean color combination of greens and blues brings a warm inviting feeling to a kitchen backsplash or bathroom. The colors work very well with white cabinetry or larger tiles. We also carry this product in a small subway mosaic to give you some options! SOLD OUT: Back in stock end of August. Call us to pre-order and save 10%!"})
```

This query produces one result:

```
MATCH (p)-->(:group)-->(i:node)
  WHERE (i.name =~ "(?i).*mosaic.*")
  RETURN i

> Returned 1 row in 569 ms
```

But this query produces zero results even though the description property matches the expression:

```
MATCH (p)-->(:group)-->(i:node)
  WHERE (i.description=~ "(?i).*mosaic.*")
  RETURN i

> Returned 0 rows in 601 ms
```

And this query also produces zero results even though it includes the name property which returned results previously:

```
MATCH (p)-->(:group)-->(i:node)
  WITH i, (p.name + i.name + COALESCE(i.description, "")) AS searchText
  WHERE (searchText =~ "(?i).*mosaic.*")
  RETURN i

> Returned 0 rows in 487 ms

MATCH (p)-->(:group)-->(i:node)
  WITH i, (p.name + i.name + COALESCE(i.description, "")) AS searchText
  RETURN searchText

>
...
SotoLinear Glass Mosaic Tiles Introducing our new Rip Curl linear glass mosaic tiles. This Caribbean color combination of greens and blues brings a warm inviting feeling to a kitchen backsplash or bathroom. The colors work very well with white cabinetry or larger tiles. We also carry this product in a small subway mosaic to give you some options! SOLD OUT: Back in stock end of August. Call us to pre-order and save 10%!
...
```

[image: mosaic]

Even more odd, if I search for a different term, it returns all of the expected results without a problem.

```
MATCH (p)-->(:group)-->(i:node)
  WITH i, (p.name + i.name + COALESCE(i.description, "")) AS searchText
  WHERE (searchText =~ "(?i).*plumbing.*")
  RETURN i

> Returned 8 rows in 522 ms
```

I then tried to cache the search text on the nodes and I added an index to see if that would change anything, but it still didn't produce any results.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :node(searchText)

MATCH (p)-->(:group)-->(i:node)
  WHERE (i.searchText =~ "(?i).*mosaic.*")
  RETURN i

> Returned 0 rows in 3182 ms
```

I then tried to simplify the data to reproduce the problem, but in this simple case it works as expected:

```
MERGE (i:node {name: "Linear Glass Mosaic Tiles", description: "Introducing our new Rip Curl linear glass mosaic tiles. This Caribbean color combination of greens and blues brings a warm inviting feeling to a kitchen backsplash or bathroom. The colors work very well with white cabinetry or larger tiles. We also carry this product in a small subway mosaic to give you some options! SOLD OUT: Back in stock end of August. Call us to pre-order and save 10%!"})

WITH i, (
  i.name + " " + COALESCE(i.description, "")
) AS searchText

WHERE searchText =~ "(?i).*mosaic.*"
RETURN i

> Returned 1 rows in 630 ms
```

I tried using the CYPHER 2.1.EXPERIMENTAL tag as well but that didn't change any of the results. Am I making incorrect assumptions on how the regex support works? Is there something else I should try or some other way to debug the problem?

**Additional information**

Here is a sample call that I make to the Cypher Transactional Rest API when creating my nodes. This is the actual plain text that is sent (other than some formatting for easier reading) when adding nodes to the database. Any string encoding is just standard URL encoding that is performed by Go when creating a new HTTP request.

```
{"statements":[
    {
    "parameters":
        {
        "p01":"lsF30nP7TsyFh",
        "p02":
            {
            "description":"Introducing our new Rip Curl linear glass mosaic tiles. This Caribbean color combination of greens and blues brings a warm inviting feeling to a kitchen backsplash or bathroom. The colors work very well with white cabinetry or larger tiles. We also carry this product in a small subway mosaic to give you some options! SOLD OUT: Back in stock end of August. Call us to pre-order and save 10%!",
            "id":"lsF3BxzFdn0kj",
            "name":"Linear Glass Mosaic Tiles",
            "object":"material"
            }
        },
    "resultDataContents":["row"],
    "statement":
        "MATCH (p:project { id: { p01 } })
        WITH p

        CREATE UNIQUE (p)-[:MATERIAL]->(:materials:group {name: \"Materials\"})-[:MATERIAL]->(m:material  { p02 })"
    }
]}
```

If it is an encoding issue, why does a search on `name` work, `description` not work, and `name` + `description` not work?  Is there any way to examine the database to see if/how the data was encoded. When I perform searches, the text returned appears correct.

Comment: I have tried with exactly the same text and regex and it's working. Maybe you are having problems with the encoding, so try updating the node and setting the same description (copy & paste, not `i.description = i.description`).

Comment: How does one have a problem with the encoding? I'm using the rest interface to save strings, not sure how to do it any differently. Is there a setting somewhere I need to be aware of? Also this wouldn't explain why `i.name` produces results but `i.name + i.description` would not produce results even if `i.description` was somehow encoded incorrectly.

Comment: Perhaps you have an invisible character in one one of the strings, like an binary 0 ? Which might throw off the pattern matcher?

Comment: I also think it might be an encoding issue.

Comment: How did you create the data?

Comment: I've added the query that I use to create my nodes. If it is an encoding issue, is there anyway to debug that? Queries all look correct to me because they are obviously being transformed by the various layers, how do I see the raw data in the database?

Comment: There are only ascii characters in the name and description in the example above, so I don't see how it could be an encoding issue, though double check by running the `file` command on it: `file example.json`

Comment: Output of a query written to disk that fails search was: query.json: ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators

Comment: Bill is there any chance you could stop the database, zip it up, and share it?

Comment: The database has customer data in it, so unfortunately I can't share it. Any way to debug myself? I'll also try create a test db that exhibits the same the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just a few notes:

- probably replace create unique with merge (which works a bit differently)
- for your fulltext search I would go with the [lucene legacy index](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/) for performance, if your group restriction is not limiting enough to keep the response below a few ms

I just tried your exact json statement, and it **works perfectly**.

inserted with

```
curl -H accept:application/json -H content-type:application/json -d @insert.json \
     -XPOST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit
```

json:

```
{"statements":[
    {
    "parameters":
        {
        "p01":"lsF30nP7TsyFh",
        "p02":
            {
            "description":"Introducing our new Rip Curl linear glass mosaic tiles. This Caribbean color combination of greens and blues brings a warm inviting feeling to a kitchen backsplash or bathroom. The colors work very well with white cabinetry or larger tiles. We also carry this product in a small subway mosaic to give you some options! SOLD OUT: Back in stock end of August. Call us to pre-order and save 10%!",
            "id":"lsF3BxzFdn0kj",
            "name":"Linear Glass Mosaic Tiles",
            "object":"material"
            }
        },
    "resultDataContents":["row"],
    "statement":
        "MERGE (p:project { id: { p01 } })
        WITH p

        CREATE UNIQUE (p)-[:MATERIAL]->(:materials:group {name: \"Materials\"})-[:MATERIAL]->(m:material  { p02 }) RETURN m"
    }
]}
```

queried:

```
MATCH (p)-->(:group)-->(i:material)
 WHERE (i.description=~ "(?i).*mosaic.*")
 RETURN i
```

returns:

```
name:   Linear Glass Mosaic Tiles
id: lsF3BxzFdn0kj
description:    Introducing our new Rip Curl linear glass mosaic tiles. This Caribbean color combination of greens and blues brings a warm inviting feeling to a kitchen backsplash or bathroom. The colors work very well with white cabinetry or larger tiles. We also carry this product in a small subway mosaic to give you some options! SOLD OUT: Back in stock end of August. Call us to pre-order and save 10%!
object: material
```

What you can try to check your data is to look at the json or csv dumps that the browser offers (little download icons on the result and table-result)

Or you use neo4j-shell with my [shell-import-tools](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#cypher-import) to actually output csv or graphml and check those files.

Or use a bit of java (or groovy) code to check your data.

There is also the consistency-checker that comes with the neo4j-enterprise download. Here is a [blog post](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/01/22/neo4j-backup-store-copy-and-consistency-check/) on how to run it.

```
java -cp 'lib/*:system/lib/*' org.neo4j.consistency.ConsistencyCheckTool /tmp/foo
```

I added a groovy test script here: https://gist.github.com/jexp/5a183c3501869ee63d30

#### One more idea: regexp flags

Sometimes there is a multiline thing going on, there are two more flags:

- `multiline (?m)` which also matches across multiple lines and
- `dotall (?s)` which allows the dot also to match special chars like newlines

So could you try `(?ism).*mosaic.*`

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but I don't think I did anything out of the ordinary. I recorded a GIF showing the problem at https://gfycat.com/ConfusedPartialIggypops#?format=gif (just so somebody can help confirm I'm not crazy). I show finding the node using the `name` property, showing the output is plain text (there is a bit of delay, here be patient), and then showing the failure using the `description` property. I also used your tool and there is nothing odd I can see in the text.

Comment: Really really weird, sorry that you have this issue. I could provide you with a groovy program to run, which would output a hexdump of the description property.

Comment: Added the test-script.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I ran the script and posted the results at https://gist.github.com/bunkat/700570ec5974c24289d2. I don't see any encoding issue, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Could you try the following: `match (n:material) where n.id = 'lsF3BxzFdn0kj' return n.description =~ '(?i).*mosaic.*' as matches, n.description as desc`

Comment: After your query worked, I tried some more things and I think I narrowed it down.  See http://i.imgur.com/NUnZUm1.png to see the comparison. The first description matches, the second one fails to match. The debug output for the failing description is at https://gist.github.com/bunkat/700570ec5974c24289d2.

Comment: That is really weird, I had another idea. Could you try to re-set the description for those failing nodes (perhaps on a copy of the store and try again if the match still fails) ? I think I extend the groovy script to test the match too.

Comment: I added some other idea about other regexp flags.

Comment: It was the regex flag (?is) works like a charm.  Might want to add that one to the documentation at http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/query-where.html.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Glad we resolved it, but it shouldn't be needed, if there are no newlines in the text.

Comment: There were line feeds though `hex (a)`.  Does the Java regex treat line feeds the same as newlines?