# Why does my neo4j request return 0 results?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have one node with 26 properties.
When I request with LIKE in the first property, it returns well a row
but when I request in the twentieth property for example, it returns me 0 row.
However the syntax of the request is the same,

```
MATCH (node:NODE) WHERE (node.prop_1 =~ "(?i).*something.*") RETURN node
```

This request returns rows and in the result, the prop_23 contains effectively "abc" and when I request this:

```
MATCH (node:NODE) WHERE (node.prop_23 =~ "(?i).*abc.*") RETURN node
```

I receive: Returned 0 rows in 531 ms

I don't understand why I can't have a result.

Comment: example looks fine, but may be in original query there is some typo

Comment: What do you mean by "effectively"? Can you provide some Cypher code to create data that shows the issue when using your second query?

Comment: the queries look fine, please provide test data

Comment: You can test if this might be because of bad data (in the value itself or the parameter name) by trying out this query: `MATCH (node:NODE) WHERE node.prop_23 CONTAINS "abc" RETURN node`. If it doesn't return data, then there's likely some kind of bad data issue in play.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, the issue is not because the data is bad but in my request, I should add sm in the (?i).

Finally, the request will be like this : 
    MATCH (node:NODE) WHERE (node.prop_23 =~ "(?ism).*abc.*") RETURN node

Thank you!!!!

Comment: I get it from the following link : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571379/neo4j-regex-string-matching-not-returning-expected-results)